# Javac Ant Build error

Tags: java, ant, build, javac, build.xml

I can link the files that are suppose to be built but this is the current error I get.

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\build.xml
clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\build
compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\build
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\build.xml:51: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 706 source files to C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\build
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\model\Instance\L1PcInstance.java:1256: error: method getId in class L1Object cannot be applied to given types;
    [javac]                                     pstm.setInt(1, player.getId(1));
    [javac]                                                          ^
    [javac]   required: no arguments
    [javac]   found: int
    [javac]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\model\Instance\L1PcInstance.java:1257: error: method getName in class L1Character cannot be applied to given types;
    [javac]                                     pstm.setString(2, player.getName(1));
    [javac]                                                             ^
    [javac]   required: no arguments
    [javac]   found: int
    [javac]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\model\Instance\L1PcInstance.java:1258: error: method getLevel in class L1Character cannot be applied to given types;
    [javac]                                     pstm.setInt(3, player.getLevel(1));
    [javac]                                                          ^
    [javac]   required: no arguments
    [javac]   found: int
    [javac]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\model\Instance\L1PcInstance.java:1259: error: method getId in class L1Object cannot be applied to given types;
    [javac]                                     pstm.setInt(4, getId(1));
    [javac]                                                    ^
    [javac]   required: no arguments
    [javac]   found: int
    [javac]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\model\Instance\L1PcInstance.java:1260: error: method getName in class L1Character cannot be applied to given types;
    [javac]                                     pstm.setString(5, getName(1));
    [javac]                                                       ^
    [javac]   required: no arguments
    [javac]   found: int
    [javac]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\model\Instance\L1PcInstance.java:1261: error: method getLevel in class L1Character cannot be applied to given types;
    [javac]                                     pstm.setInt(6, getLevel(1));
    [javac]                                                    ^
    [javac]   required: no arguments
    [javac]   found: int
    [javac]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\model\Instance\L1PcInstance.java:1263: error: method getX in class L1Object cannot be applied to given types;
    [javac]                                     pstm.setInt(8, getX(1));
    [javac]                                                    ^
    [javac]   required: no arguments
    [javac]   found: int
    [javac]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\model\Instance\L1PcInstance.java:1264: error: method getY in class L1Object cannot be applied to given types;
    [javac]                                     pstm.setInt(9, getY(1));
    [javac]                                                    ^
    [javac]   required: no arguments
    [javac]   found: int
    [javac]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\model\Instance\L1PcInstance.java:1265: error: method getMapId in class L1Object cannot be applied to given types;
    [javac]                                     pstm.setInt(10, getMapId(1));
    [javac]                                                     ^
    [javac]   required: no arguments
    [javac]   found: int
    [javac]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\model\Instance\L1PcInstance.java:1269: error: method isEnabledDeathPenalty in class L1Map cannot be applied to given types;
    [javac]                                             && getMap().isEnabledDeathPenalty(1)) {
    [javac]                                                        ^
    [javac]   required: no arguments
    [javac]   found: int
    [javac]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\model\L1MobSkillUse.java:458: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Constructor
    [javac]                     Constructor _constructor = Class
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Constructor<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Constructor
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\ThreadPoolManager.java:94: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: ScheduledFuture
    [javac]     public ScheduledFuture scheduleEffect(Runnable r, long delay) {
    [javac]            ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class ScheduledFuture<V>
    [javac]   where V is a type-variable:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in interface ScheduledFuture
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\ThreadPoolManager.java:106: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: ScheduledFuture
    [javac]     public ScheduledFuture scheduleEffectAtFixedRate(Runnable r, long initial,
    [javac]            ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class ScheduledFuture<V>
    [javac]   where V is a type-variable:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in interface ScheduledFuture
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\ThreadPoolManager.java:122: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: ScheduledFuture
    [javac]     public ScheduledFuture scheduleGeneral(Runnable r, long delay) {
    [javac]            ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class ScheduledFuture<V>
    [javac]   where V is a type-variable:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in interface ScheduledFuture
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\ThreadPoolManager.java:134: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: ScheduledFuture
    [javac]     public ScheduledFuture scheduleGeneralAtFixedRate(Runnable r, long initial,
    [javac]            ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class ScheduledFuture<V>
    [javac]   where V is a type-variable:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in interface ScheduledFuture
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\ThreadPoolManager.java:150: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: ScheduledFuture
    [javac]     public ScheduledFuture scheduleAi(Runnable r, long delay) {
    [javac]            ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class ScheduledFuture<V>
    [javac]   where V is a type-variable:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in interface ScheduledFuture
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\ThreadPoolManager.java:162: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: ScheduledFuture
    [javac]     public ScheduledFuture scheduleAiAtFixedRate(Runnable r, long initial,
    [javac]            ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class ScheduledFuture<V>
    [javac]   where V is a type-variable:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in interface ScheduledFuture
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\clientpackets\C_Attr.java:314: warning: [static] static method should be qualified by type name, CharacterTable, instead of by an expression
    [javac]                     CharacterTable.getInstance().updatePartnerId(
    [javac]                                                 ^
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\clientpackets\C_CreateChar.java:213: warning: [static] static method should be qualified by type name, CharacterTable, instead of by an expression
    [javac]         CharacterTable.getInstance().saveCharStatus(pc);
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\clientpackets\C_ItemUSe.java:5190: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Constructor
    [javac]                         Constructor constructor = Class.forName(
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Constructor<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Constructor
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\clientpackets\C_Mail.java:55: warning: [static] static method should be qualified by type name, MailTable, instead of by an expression
    [javac]             L1Mail mail = MailTable.getInstance().getMail(mailId);
    [javac]                                                  ^
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\clientpackets\C_Mail.java:133: warning: [static] static method should be qualified by type name, MailTable, instead of by an expression
    [javac]         for (L1Mail mail : MailTable.getInstance().getAllMail()) {
    [javac]                                                   ^
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\clientpackets\C_Result.java:458: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: List
    [javac]             List sellList;
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class List<E>
    [javac]   where E is a type-variable:
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in interface List
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\clientpackets\C_Result.java:541: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to set(int,E) as a member of the raw type List
    [javac]                                 sellList.set(order, pssl);
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac]   where E is a type-variable:
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in interface List
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\clientpackets\C_Result.java:566: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: List
    [javac]             List buyList;
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class List<E>
    [javac]   where E is a type-variable:
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in interface List
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\clientpackets\C_Result.java:640: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to set(int,E) as a member of the raw type List
    [javac]                             buyList.set(order, psbl);
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac]   where E is a type-variable:
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in interface List
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\clientpackets\C_Shop.java:70: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: List
    [javac]         List sellList = pc.getSellList();
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class List<E>
    [javac]   where E is a type-variable:
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in interface List
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\clientpackets\C_Shop.java:71: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: List
    [javac]         List buyList = pc.getBuyList();
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class List<E>
    [javac]   where E is a type-variable:
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in interface List
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\clientpackets\C_Shop.java:124: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type List
    [javac]                 sellList.add(pssl);
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac]   where E is a type-variable:
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in interface List
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\clientpackets\C_Shop.java:185: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type List
    [javac]                 buyList.add(psbl);
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac]   where E is a type-variable:
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in interface List
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\command\executor\L1GfxId.java:51: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Constructor
    [javac]                     Constructor constructor = Class.forName(
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Constructor<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Constructor
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\datatables\FurnitureSpawnTable.java:70: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Constructor
    [javac]                     Constructor constructor = Class.forName(
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Constructor<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Constructor
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\datatables\LightSpawnTable.java:68: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Constructor
    [javac]                     Constructor constructor = Class.forName(
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Constructor<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Constructor
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\datatables\TrapTable.java:48: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Constructor
    [javac]         Constructor con = Class.forName(packageName + name).getConstructor(
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Constructor<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Constructor
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\datatables\TrapTable.java:49: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Class
    [javac]                 new Class[] { TrapStorage.class });
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Class<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Class
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\model\L1EffectSpawn.java:41: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Constructor
    [javac]     private Constructor _constructor;
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Constructor<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Constructor
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\model\L1War.java:59: warning: [static] static method should be qualified by type name, WarTimeController, instead of by an expression
    [javac]                             .getRealTime())) {
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\model\L1World.java:66: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: ConcurrentHashMap
    [javac]         _visibleObjects = new ConcurrentHashMap[MAX_MAP_ID + 1];
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class ConcurrentHashMap<K,V>
    [javac]   where K,V are type-variables:
    [javac]     K extends Object declared in class ConcurrentHashMap
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in class ConcurrentHashMap
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\model\npc\action\L1NpcActionFactory.java:35: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Class
    [javac]     private static Constructor<L1NpcAction> loadConstructor(Class c)
    [javac]                                                             ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Class<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Class
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\model\npc\action\L1NpcActionFactory.java:37: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Class
    [javac]         return c.getConstructor(new Class[] { Element.class });
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Class<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Class
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\model\skill\L1SkillTimer.java:669: warning: [deprecation] stop() in Thread has been deprecated
    [javac]         super.stop();
    [javac]              ^
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\serverpackets\S_Mail.java:38: warning: [static] static method should be qualified by type name, MailTable, instead of by an expression
    [javac]         for (L1Mail mail : MailTable.getInstance().getAllMail()) {
    [javac]                                                   ^
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\serverpackets\S_Mail.java:79: warning: [static] static method should be qualified by type name, MailTable, instead of by an expression
    [javac]         L1Mail mail = MailTable.getInstance().getMail(mailId);
    [javac]                                              ^
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\taskmanager\TaskManager.java:63: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: ScheduledFuture
    [javac]         ScheduledFuture _scheduled;
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class ScheduledFuture<V>
    [javac]   where V is a type-variable:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in interface ScheduledFuture
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\taskmanager\Task.java:39: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: ScheduledFuture
    [javac]     public ScheduledFuture launchSpecial(ExecutedTask instance) {
    [javac]            ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class ScheduledFuture<V>
    [javac]   where V is a type-variable:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in interface ScheduledFuture
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\utils\LeakCheckedConnection.java:45: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Class
    [javac]                 new Class[] { Connection.class }, new ConnectionHandler());
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Class<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Class
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\utils\LeakCheckedConnection.java:116: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Class
    [javac]                     new Class[] { c }, this);
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Class<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Class
    [javac] C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\src\l1j\server\server\utils\collections\Lists.java:35: warning: [unchecked] Possible heap pollution from parameterized vararg type E
    [javac]     public static <E> List<E> of(E... elements) {
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac]   where E is a type-variable:
    [javac]     E extends Object declared in method <E>of(E...)
    [javac] 10 errors
    [javac] 38 warnings

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\********\Desktop\en-m8\build.xml:51: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 5 seconds
```

Comment: You seem to be passing an `int` to a method when not is required; for example `player.getId(1)`; *"required: no arguments; found: int; reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"*

Comment: Is there any reason you reset the formatting of the output in the question from been readable to been unreadable?

Comment: i was trying to get a pop up window so the code looked correct. its back to normal now.

Comment: I cant seem to post the Build.xml here too long.

Comment: Now, it's formatted and readable...any reason why this is worse then your original question?

Comment: My question is why will it not build, This file is no corrupt and this is a complete code. The older version of Eclipse wont build it with new Java8 and the new eclipse is giving this error.

Comment: Okay, so back to the question, based on the errors, you are passing a value to a method which doesn't take any parameters

Comment: The issue at hand is its not selecting all the items that are suppose to be built into a .Java  <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />
    <property name="build.dir" value="build" />
    <property name="jarfile" value="l1jen.jar" />

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar" />
            <include name="javolution.jar" />
            <include name="mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <!-- Set DefaultTarget -->
    <target name="all" depends="clea

Answer (score 1):

Each error is telling you what is wrong, for example

```
pstm.setInt(1, player.getId(1));
```

should be

```
pstm.setInt(1, player.getId());
```

because

> ```
> [javac]   required: no arguments
> [javac]   found: int
> [javac]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
> ```